# Referencing output of vpc endpoint id from public module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/tree/v5.1.1/modules/vpc-endpoints

```
module "vpc_endpoint" {
  source  = "./modules/vpc-endpoints"

  vpc_id            = "vpc-xxxx"
  endpoints         = {
    vpce = {
      service = null
      service_name = "${module.es_nlb.endpoint_service_service_name}" 
      vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
    }
  }
  security_group_ids  = ["sg-xxx"]
  subnet_ids          = ["subnet-xxx","subnet-xxxxx"]
}`
```

I need to call the output of VPC endpoint ID from the VPC endpoint module of the above source code to the below code for the acceptor. But currently the output of this source code supports only the value endpoints which is "Array containing the full resource object and attributes for all endpoints created". Below is the output that comes for endpoints. i need to pick the value of "id" from this output and reference with the module created above for endpoint. Requirement is to get output only as vpc endpoint id by referencing module.

```
endpoints = {
  "endpoints" = {
    "vpce" = {
      "arn" = "arn:aws:ec2:<region>:xx:vpc-endpoint/vpce-xx"
      "auto_accept" = tobool(null)
      "cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
      "dns_entry" = tolist([
        {
          "dns_name" = "vpce-xx-1y5z27zq.vpce-svc-xx.ap-south-1.vpce.amazonaws.com"
          "hosted_zone_id" = "Z2KVTB3ZLFM7JR"
        },
        {
          "dns_name" = "vpce-xx-1y5z27zq-region.vpce-svc-xx-1.vpce.amazonaws.com"
          "hosted_zone_id" = "Z2KVTB3ZLFM7JR"
        },
        {
          "dns_name" = "vpce-xx-1y5z27zq-region.vpce-svc-xxx.ap-south-1.vpce.amazonaws.com"
          "hosted_zone_id" = "Z2KVTB3ZLFM7JR"
        },
      ])
      "dns_options" = tolist([
        {
          "dns_record_ip_type" = "ipv4"
          "private_dns_only_for_inbound_resolver_endpoint" = false
        },
      ])
      "id" = "vpce-xxx"
      "ip_address_type" = "ipv4"
      "network_interface_ids" = toset([
        "eni-xx",
        "eni-xx",
      ])
      "owner_id" = "xx"
      "policy" = "{\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":\"*\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Resource\":\"*\"}]}"
      "prefix_list_id" = tostring(null)
      "private_dns_enabled" = false
      "requester_managed" = false
      "route_table_ids" = toset([])
      "security_group_ids" = toset([
        "sg-xx",
      ])
      "service_name" = "com.amazonaws.vpce.region.vpce-xx"
      "state" = "pendingAcceptance"
      "subnet_ids" = toset([
        "subnet-xx",
        "subnet-xx",
      ])
      "timeouts" = {
        "create" = "10m"
        "delete" = "10m"
        "update" = "10m"
      }
      "vpc_endpoint_type" = "Interface"
      "vpc_id" = "vpc-xxx"
    }
  }
```

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_connection_accepter" "example" {
  vpc_endpoint_service_id = aws_vpc_endpoint_service.example.id
  vpc_endpoint_id         = <needs to reference from module of endpoint>
}
```

I tried to different way as below to reference the endpoint id value of the output as below

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_connection_accepter" "example" {
  vpc_endpoint_service_id = aws_vpc_endpoint_service.example.id
  vpc_endpoint_id         = module.vpc_endpoint.endpoints[number]
}
```

What I'm expecting is to get the vpc_endpoint_id value by referencing the module

Comment: I think it should be `module.vpc_endpoint.endpoints.vpce.id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, since the output is a map, it consists of key/value pairs. The key in this case are `endpoints`, `vpce`, and `id`, which will give you the VPC Endpoint ID:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_connection_accepter" "example" {
  vpc_endpoint_service_id = aws_vpc_endpoint_service.example.id
  vpc_endpoint_id         = module.vpc_endpoint.endpoints.vpce.id
}
```